# User secrets not available to .net core app hosted in windows service

Tags: c#, .net-core, appsettings

I am attempting to access user secrets in a .Net Core Windows Service.  The service itself is running under a service account, and I have added a user secret for the service user.

When running the application as a straightforward console application, the user secret can be accessed.  However, when running the application as a windows service, the setting cannot be read.  There is no error - just the value is not obtained.  The service is running under the same user account as the logged in user - and the secret can be obtained when running the console application.

When I add the secrets.json file to the hosted executable's location and read it in using the AddJsonFile method then the value can be read.  Here is a code snippet:

```
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();

        // does not work as a service
        builder.AddUserSecrets("TestUserSecrets");

        // works as a service when secrets.json is copied to exe directory
        // builder.AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Secrets.json"));

        Configuration = builder.Build();

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
            .CreateLogger();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory logFactory)
    {
        // attempt to obtain secret config value
        string secret = Configuration["Secret"];
```

Is there an issue with the windows service getting access to the user secret (in the secret.json file)?

Is the intention just to use user secrets for development, and therefore using user secrets in a windows service is just not going to work?

Comment: The runtime environment for a service is just very different from the one you get for a console app.  That starts with Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), in general a very ugly global variable that is only set where you hope it is by accident, it is *not* where your app is located.  env.EnvironmentName is highly questionable, a service is not an ASP.NET app.

Comment: The the built-in usersecrets configuration Provider currently fails to build from an appropriate base directory in several environments outside of IIS Express (including regular IIS, and probably Windows Services). `%AppData%` in these cases ends up in the windows directory, so the result doesn't find secrets.json. It then defaults to looking for secrets.json in the root program directory, and loads nothing when it can't find that. I didn't want to write a custom Provider and just used environment variables for dev secrets.

Answer (score 1):

> Firstly, you should take a look at the documentation about [Accessing user secrets via configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets#accessing-user-secrets-via-configuration)
>
> The documentation will help you to understand how to work with user secrets properly.

You noted that

```
builder.AddUserSecrets("TestUserSecrets");
```

does not work properly... take a look at the code block below to see how I have adapted your code to meet the documentation:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddUserSecrets<Startup>(); // <-- note here
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    Configuration = builder.Build();
}

public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    string testSecret = Configuration["Secret"];
}
```

### How the Secret Manager tool works

The Secret Manager tool abstracts away the implementation details, such as where and how the values are stored. You can use the tool without knowing these implementation details. **In the current version, the values are stored in a JSON configuration file in the user profile directory:**

> - **Windows: `%APPDATA%\microsoft\UserSecrets\<userSecretsId>\secrets.json`**
> - Linux: `~/.microsoft/usersecrets/<userSecretsId>/secrets.json`
> - Mac: `~/.microsoft/usersecrets/<userSecretsId>/secrets.json`

The value of `userSecretsId` comes from the value specified in `.csproj` file.
You should not write code that depends on the location or format of the data saved with the Secret Manager tool, as these implementation details might change. For example, the secret values are currently not encrypted today, but could be someday.

---

### Alternative Solution

I do run into the same situation as you quite often trying to use the Secret Manager tool (is not for everyone, nor every situation).

My typical solution is to do what you already noted:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

try
{
    string secretsFile = Path.GetFullPath("../secrets.json");
    builder.AddJsonFile(secretsFile , optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { } // this resolves an error from hosts trying to go 
                                        // below the root.
```

As you can see, it will attempt to grab the `secrets.json` file from the provided path. However, you should note that in the event you host the application, you are most likely going to store them on to the environment variables, or otherwise in which case this case is already fine. Otherwise, just adapt the code to meet your specific environment.

Note:

```
string secretsFile = Path.GetFullPath("../secrets.json");
```

I intentionally popped out the `secrets.json` **below the root directory** here, since we don't want to accidentally put our `secrets.json` into the repository if you are using any source control.

Answer (score 0):

My alternative workaround solution is to use an [`option`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2) which will have IConfiguration type property. In constructor call `IOptions` instead of `Iconfiguration`.

> MyOptions.cs

```
public class MyOptions
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
}
```

> Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
        {    
            public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
            {
                var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    builder.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();
                }
                else
                {
                    builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                }

                Configuration = builder.Build();
            }

            public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

            public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                services.Configure<MyOptions>(opt =>
                {
                    opt.Configuration = Configuration;
                });

                services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            }
        }
```

> And access it like

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
public class MyController
    {
        readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        public MyController(IOptions<MyOptions> options)
        {
            _configuration = options.Value.Configuration;
        }

        public void Test()
        {
            Console.Log(_configuration["Section:Value"]);
        }
    }
```